# How to get the rogue DHCP clients using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I need to get a list of the clients/computers that are not members of AD Domain but got a lease from DHCP.

The code I use looks like works for other users but I don't get any hostnames in my output file.

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -allleases -ScopeId 191.168.1.1 | Select-Object @{expression= {$_.hostname}; label='name' } | export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\dhcp\LeaseLog.csv

$leaselogpath = "c:\DHCP\LeaseLog.csv"
Import-csv -path $leaselogpath | foreach-object {
    $ComputerName = $_.name.Replace(".domain.com",$null)
    $Result = Get-ADComputer $ComputerName
    If ($Result -eq $null) {
        $RogueSystem = $_.Name
    }
    $RogueSystem | Out-File C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt -Append $RogueSystem = $null
}
```

Upon execution I got error messages about the computers missing in domain - exctly the computers I need listed in the output file, but the output file remains empty.

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TEST-PC1'....

Comment: The code you posted is broken due to incorred (or, more specifically, missing) line breaks. Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the code you have in your script. We cannot help you when the code you post introduces additional issues that are not present in the code you're trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with resetting $Result

```
$ScopeID = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName DC1 | select ScopeID

$ScopeID | foreach-object `
{
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -allleases -ScopeId $_.ScopeID -ComputerName DC1  | Select-Object @{expression= {$_.hostname}; label='name' } | export-CSV -notypeinformation C:\dhcp\LeaseLog.csv -Append
}

$leaselogpath = "c:\DHCP\LeaseLog.csv"
Import-csv -path $leaselogpath | 
#query AD for computer name based on csv log
foreach-object `
{ 
   $ComputerName = $_.name.Replace(".domain.com",$null)
   $Result = $null
   $Result = Get-ADComputer $ComputerName -ErrorAction Continue
   If ($Result -eq $null) {$RogueSystem = $_.Name}
   $RogueSystem | Out-File C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt -Append
   $RogueSystem = $null

}
```

Just added a command to get all the ScopeIDs from a specified domain controller and list all the leases in a csv file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Try...Catch would add clarity

```
# query AD for computer name based on csv log 
Import-csv -path $leaselogpath | foreach-object {
    Try {
        $ComputerName = $_.name.Replace(".domain.com",$null)
        $Result = Get-ADComputer $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
         Write-Error $_
         $RogueSystem = $_.Name
         $RogueSystem | Out-File C:\DHCP\RogueClients.txt -Append
         $RogueSystem = $null 
    }
}
```